# How to change range of date on arrow click? [Nuxt]

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, nuxt.js

I'm making a weekly schedule in Vue in which I have a bar showing range from Monday to Sunday with previous and next arrows. It looks like that:[image]

Maj means May and Czerwiec - June
In code I have two methods of getting Monday and Sunday:

```
getMonday(date) {
  date = new Date(date);
  let day = date.getDay();
  let dayDifference = date.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -5 : 1);
  let d = new Date(date.setDate(dayDifference));
  let dayOfTheMonth = d.getDate();
  let month = this.months[d.getMonth()];

  let firstDay = {dayOfTheMonth, month};
  return  firstDay;
},
getSunday(date) {
  date = new Date(date);
  let day = date.getDay();
  let dayDifference = date.getDate() + day + (day == 0 ? +4 : 5);
  let d = new Date(date.setDate(dayDifference));
  let dayOfTheMonth = d.getDate();
  let month = this.months[d.getMonth()];

  let lastDay = {dayOfTheMonth, month};
  return lastDay;
},
```

I display them like this:

```
 <h1 id="currentWeek">{{ getMonday(new Date()).dayOfTheMonth }} {{ getMonday(new Date()).month }}
        - {{ getSunday(new Date()).dayOfTheMonth }} {{ getSunday(new Date()).month }}</h1>
```

And now the problem is that I don't know how to display new week range on arrow click. First of all I can't get the correct range when I add or subtract from the date 6. Second of all when I finally could change the date but still uncorrectly, in the h1 the date didn't change

```
 prev(date) {
  this.getMonday(date - 6);
  this.getSunday(date - 6);
  console.log(this.getMonday(date - 6), this.getSunday(date - 6))
},
next(date) {
  this.getMonday(date + 6);
  this.getSunday(date + 6);
  console.log(this.getMonday(date + 6), this.getSunday(date + 6))
},`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that: don't mess with dates, unless you really want to mess with dates.

There are a number of really cool (and not too big) packages that simplify this topic, like [dayjs](https://day.js.org/).

Here's a little snippet to prove this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      currentWeek: 0,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.currentWeek = dayjs().week()
  },
  computed: {
    startDisplayedWeek() {
      return dayjs().week(this.currentWeek).startOf("week").format("DD. MMMM")
    },
    endDisplayedWeek() {
      return dayjs().week(this.currentWeek).endOf("week").format("DD. MMMM")
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Current week: {{ currentWeek }}<br />
      <div>
        <span
          class="week-stepper"
          @click="currentWeek -= 1"
        ><</span>
        {{ startDisplayedWeek }} - {{ endDisplayedWeek }}
        <span
          class="week-stepper"
          @click="currentWeek += 1"
        >></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```css
.week-stepper {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/plugin/weekOfYear.js"></script>
<script>
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_weekOfYear)
</script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Dates** are a notoriously hard topic - so many edge cases, time zones, and other things to take care of. It's **MUCH** easier to avoid the pitfalls with a solution that's purpose-built.

When does a week start? Monday or Sunday? What time zone are you in, what time zones are the users in? What's the difference (in days) between today and 31/08/2045? Of course, these might be questions that you don't intend to service with your software - but I think it's better to sleep with the feeling that "I did not miss the date with +1 day in the code somewhere." :)

Comment: Totally agreed on this one. A library used for dates is still the less error-prone and battle-tested solution that you can find. On top of being fast to implement. Drop the homemade solution and use a popular one. This or `date-fns` are both good.